# bootstrap popover animation velocity transition.flipBounceYIn, the data-trigger=focus didn't work perfectely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

when i'm using bootstrap popover with animation velocity transition.flipBounceYIn the data-trigger=focus  didn't work perfectely
so when i first click the glyphicon the popover open with animation when i re-click on the popover it is reopen ...
what i need is to let this popover still opened without flashing or reopen ..just still open without any actions and when i click outside i want it to close
...i used data-trigger="focus" it let me close the popover when i click outside but it still reopen when i click on the popover 
please anyone help me.

```
<a  class="pointer-glyphicon" ><span   rel="popover" data-animation="false" style="float:right; margin-top:25px; color: #c8c8c8; " class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign "  tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-auto-close="false" title="Popover title" data-content="Default popover" data-placement="top"></span></a>
javascript:
 $('span[rel=popover]').popover().click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  
        $(this).next().velocity('transition.flipBounceYIn');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bootstrap Modal and popover with Velocity.js animation</title>



    <link rel=stylesheet href="css/bootstrap.min.css">




  </head>

  <body>

          <a href="#myModal5"  data-toggle="modal">flipBounceYIn</a>


        <div id="myModal5" class="modal" data-easein="flipBounceYIn" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal header 1</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body…</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>


        </div>
      </div>
      <div> </div>
  </div>
     <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

### And index.js

```
$( ".modal" ).each(function(index) {
   $(this).on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { 
     $('.modal-dialog').velocity('transition.flipBounceYIn');


}); 
});
```